# How to maintain paragraph styling after text replacement in the paragraph using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am facing problem in formatting Docx file using python docx library.
I am able to replace some text in a  paragraph but can't maintain text font. Below is my approach -

```
from docx import Document

# read doc file
doc = Document(file name)
```

now I need to replace few words in a paragraph,(lets say replace a key in the paragraph by val) and paragraph index(pid) is known  so I am performing following tasks:

```
paragraph = doc.paragraphs[int(pid)].text

para = re.sub(key, val, paragraph.rstrip())  
doc.paragraphs[pid].text = para
```

After saving this document, now I can see replaced text in the file but not able to maintain the font. I mean earlier common font in the file was "Times New Roman" but after text replacement paragraph font and weight is different. So how can I maintain the paragraph font and other styling similar to before text replacement.

P.S. got a good response in google web2py user group that it can be done at run level but problem is, text I want to replace is not a single run but chunks of run.

I also tried extracting the paragraph font style but docx library does'nt return correct font.